# Cannot read property '[function]' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm writing in Typescript with Ionic 2.2.1 in my home.ts class.

I get the error: **TypeError: this.GetLocalInformation is not a function**
on execution.

Here are how the two functions interact:

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.GetLocalInformation(); //sets this.school to the school
this.fullSchedule = this.schedProvider.GetCorrespondingSchool(this.school);
this.fullSchoolName = this.schedProvider.GetFullSchoolName(this.school);


this.timerFunc(); //Timer Function -- This method is in a loop with itself
}

timerFunc() { //Self Updating Timer Method
this.GetLocalInformation();
this.periods = this.schedProvider.GetPeriod(this.school);
this.timeInSeconds = ((this.periods[0].h * 3600) + (this.periods[0].m * 60)) - (new Date().getHours() * 3600 + new Date().getMinutes() * 60) - new Date().getSeconds(); //Calculate time difference
this.currentP = this.periods[0].title;
this.nextP = this.periods[1].title;

var dt = Date.now() - this.expected; // the drift (positive for overshooting)
if (dt > this.interval) {
  // something really bad happened. Maybe the browser (tab) was inactive?
  // possibly special handling to avoid futile "catch up" run
}
//Set Variables

//Update Timer
//this.timer.timer.secondsRemaining = +this.timeInSeconds;
this.timer.updateTimer(this.timeInSeconds);
this.expected += this.interval;
setTimeout(this.timerFunc, Math.max(0, this.interval - dt)); // take into account drift
}
```

I receive the error on the first line of **timerFunc()**, which makes no sense because I called that same function perfectly fine in **ngOnInit()**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're losing your `this` context when you pass in `this.timerFunc` into the `setTimeout` function. To properly bind your scope you can use `.bind(this)`:

```
setTimeout(this.timerFunc.bind(this), Math.max(0, this.interval - dt)
```

Or use an arrow function to auto-bind `this`:

```
setTimeout(() => this.timerFunc(), Math.max(0, this.interval - dt))
```

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly and easily understood. Thank you! Much appreciated